# Docker-Java: Starting container with arguments

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

I'm trying to start a docker container using docker-java.
Using the method `DockerClient.startContainerCmd` works for me, but I need to start the container with arguments.
The `StartContainerCmd` class that is returned from this method does not have any methods to supply arguments before I execute it.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StartContainerCmd` delegates to `StartContainerCmdExec` which abstracts the [Start Container REST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerStart) operation. The Operation has only one path parameter (`id` of the container). If you need to supply additional arguments you need to create the container with those arguments:

```
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(IMAGE_NAME)
                .withCmd("cmd", "arg1", "arg2").exec()
```

get the `id` of the container and then start it:

`dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();`

Answer (score 0):

It should work easily with https://www.github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api:

```
final Docker docker = new LocalDocker(...);//or RemoteDocker(...)
final Container container = docker.containers().create(/*JsonObject*/).start();
```

The JsonObject passed to Containers.create(...) should be the one that Docker's API expects as input (see API docs). In that JsonObject, you should also be able to specify startup scripts.